# Grails does not compile in Tomcat Environment

Tags: tomcat, grails

I'm just reposting my previous question on alternate StackOverflow forum community.  But that post is currently put on hold as my post question is more technically-oriented rather than just a general-purpose question.

Here it goes

---

I'm currently working on a client's debt management software, and one of my key tasks is to improve and enhance the application's functions and features. This application is written entirely in Grails.

Recently, I received an email from a client which states the history background behind the software and one of its underlying concerns is that the Grails application is "un-compilable". Meaning it can only be compiled in Groovy environment. But it will not compile in the Tomcat environment. Even though the Grails framework already comes with a built-in Tomcat server run-time environment packages, there are notable differences between its version vs the actual Tomcat server deployment package. The client also states that the reason it cannot be compiled is because the application has too many incompatibilities issues due to its complex number of classes and functions..

May I ask how true and valid is this statement the client claims is to be? Is it common that Grails app are not suitable in post-release Tomcat server production environment? I just want to know what your thoughts on it maybe and keen to hear your advice what can I do to analyse and research this issue further before I can confidently go back to my client to discuss possible alternatives to these so-called 'un-compiled' state problem.

Here's the attached error logs (FYI)

[image]

Comment: We will be releasing a million $ application (yet another) written in Grails & deployed to Tomcat by end of this week at my client location. I hope you have the answer. :)

Comment: It's better to describe client concert more detailed. I believe he didn't mean 'cannot compile in the Tomcat' (of course Grails can compile), maybe he had more specific incompatibility issues?

Comment: That's right Igor.  It's to do with several incompatibility issues when trying to compile.  See the updated comment with the attached error log above.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't quite technically make sense, but I think I understand what you're asking, so I'll give it a go.

You don't actually compile something in a tomcat environment, rather you run something in tomcat. But grails apps can be run using `grails run-app` to run it right from the grails environment. That is suitable for development, but not for production.

Grails does have a `war` command that creates a war. At this point it is just like any other webapp that can be run in a web container such as tomcat.

A grails app does in fact require groovy to compile it, since it's groovy code, but creating a war will make it runnable in a web container.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jeff.  This helps a lot.  This is entirely new to me as well so I couldn't figure out much what's the whole story with the client app not compatible in the Tomcat environment, versus Groovy environment.  From the client's point of view, they were hoping to achieve system performance gains on Tomcat environment instead of Groovy (as suggested by the previous developer) hence they reached the conclusion the application will not compiled well in Tomcat environment.

Comment: My client show me the error logs of the unsuccessful war command deploying in Tomcat environment.  I can show you the logs and see if it makes any sense for you.

Comment: Are you saying `grails war` is failing, or that Tomcat is failing to start up once you've deployed your WAR? Can you post the error?

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Yes Grails comes with a Tomcat plugin to make local development more convenient, but this is entirely independent of how and where you deploy to production. In fact Grails previously used Jetty as its dev-mode server and still has a plugin for this.

When you deploy a Grails app to a "real" server, you just create a WAR file. The most convenient way to do this is to run `grails war` but this can be customized. This compiles all of the code, including the GSPs, and packages up everything including the JAR dependencies. Then you deploy it to Tomcat/WebLogic/JBoss/whatever - pretty much any servlet container. There's no compilation after that since the WAR file includes compiled classes. In addition there's no need to install Grails or Groovy on the server since the WAR file you create will have the Groovy JAR, Grails JARs, and all of the other dependent JARs in the WAR.

The more likely problem is that you're developing the code and sharing it with them, and they're trying to do a build and deploy it but are having dependency issues. This is unlikely to have anything to do with Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks Burt.  Like I said above comment, this is entirely new to me as well and I'm trying to gather the full picture what's troubling the client so much with their deployment setup.  I can show you the log fils if you're interested.